# Mock mysql connection with Jest

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Trying to test code that looks like this :

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

async myFunction () {

    const db = await mysql.createConnection(options);

    const results = await db.execute('SELECT `something` from `table`;');

    await db.end();
    
    // more code ...

}
```

I need to mock the the mysql connection in a way that will allow me to use whatever it returns to mock a call to the `execute` function.

I have tried mocking the whole `mysql2/promise` module but of course that did not work, since the mocked `createConnection` was not returning anything that could make a call to the `execute`  function.
I also tried only mocking these 3 functions that I need instead of mocking the whole module, something like:

```
jest.mock('mysql2/promise', () => ({
    createConnection: jest.fn(() => ({
        execute: jest.fn(),
        end: jest.fn(),
    })),
}));
```

But that did not work too.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

I would approach this differently. When you feel you need to mock entire third-party libraries for testing, something is off in your application.

As a general best practice, you should always wrap third-party libraries. Check out [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298145/wrapping-third-party-library-is-best-practice) for starters.

Basically the idea is to define your own interfaces to the desired functionality, then implement these interfaces using the third-party library. In the rest of your code, you would only work against the interfaces, not against the third-party implementation.

This has a couple of advantages

1. You can define the interfaces yourself. It will normally be much smaller than the entire third-party library, as you rarely use all functionality of that third-party library, and you can decide what's the best interface definition for your concrete use cases, rather than having to follow exactly what some library author dictates you.
2. If one day you decide you don't want to use MySQL anymore but move to Mongo, you can just write a Mongo implementation of your DB interface.
3. In your case, most importantly: You can easily create a mock implementation of your DB interface without having to start mocking the entire third-party API.

So how could this work?

First, define an interface as it would be most useful in your code. Perhaps, a DB interface for you could look like this:

```
interface Database<T> {
  create(object: T): Promise<void>;
  get(id: string): Promise<T>;
  getAll(): Promise<T[]>;
  update(id: string, object: T): Promise<void>;
  delete(id: string): Promise<void>;
}
```

Now, you can develop your entire code base against this one `Database` interface. Instead of writing MySQL queries all across your code, when you need to retrieve data from 'table', you can use your `Database` implementation.

I'll just take an example `ResultRetriever` here that is pretty primitive, but serves the purpose:

```
class ResultRetriever {
  
    constructor(private database: Database<Something>) {}

    getResults(): Promise<Something[]> {
        return this.database.getAll();
    }
  
}
```

As you can see, your code does not need to care about which DB implementation delivers the data. Also, we [inverted dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) here: `ResultReteriver` is **injected** its `Database` instance. It does not know which conrete `Database` implementation it gets. It doesn't need to. All it cares about is that it is a valid one.

You can now easily implement a MySQL `Database` class:

```
class MySqlDatabase<T> implements Database<T> {

  create(object: T): Promise<void> {...}

  get(id: string): Promise<T> {...}

  getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
      const db = await mysql.createConnection(options);
      const results = await db.execute('SELECT `something` from `table`;');
      await db.end();
      return results;
  }

  update(id: string, object: T): Promise<void> {...}

  delete(id: string): Promise<void> {...}

}
```

Now we've fully abstracted the MySQL-specific implementation from your main code base. When it comes to testing, you can write a simple `MockDatabase`:

```
export class MockDatabase<T> implements Database<T> {

  private objects: T[] = [];

  async create(object: T): Promise<void> {
    this.objects.push(object);
  }

  async get(id: string): Promise<T> {
    return this.objects.find(o => o.id === id);
  }

  async getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.objects;
  }

  update(id: string, object: T): Promise<void> {...}

  delete(id: string): Promise<void> {...}
  
}
```

When it comes to testing, you can now test your `ResultRetriever` using your `MockDatabase` instead of relying on the MySQL library and therefore on mocking it entirely:

```
describe('ResultRetriever', () => {

    let retriever: ResultRetriever;
    let db: Database;

    beforeEach(() => {
      db = new MockDatabase();
      retriever = new ResultRetriever(db);
    });

    ...

});
```

---

I am sorry if I went a bit beyond the scope of the question, but I felt just responding how to mock the MySQL library was not going to solve the underlying architectural issue.

If you are not using/don't want to use TypeScript, the same logics can be applied to JavaScript.

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me a good understanding of how I should be structuring things and I appreciate it a lot, I will have to do more reading on this topic it looks interesting. One thing that I still wonder is that even with this approach, won't I face the same situation again when it comes to actually testing the `MySqlDatabase` implementation ?

Comment: I would pose the question whether testing the MySqlDatabase implementation with mock data would serve any purpose. At the end, if you have a skinny implementation that just translates between your Database interface and the MySql library, all you'd test by mocking is that your mock works corretly, but it would say nothing whether your MySQL implementaiton actually works. So I'd argue if you want to test your MySQL implementation, do that against a (temporary) actual MySQL DB. You can for sure spin one up and down just before/after the testing.

Comment: I would want my build to break for example if there is an update on that external library that could potentially break my code, or in cases that a dev removes the call that ends the connection to the database. So, when testing code that speaks to a database you are suggesting writing integration tests instead of unit tests ?

Comment: The actual concern you have is your MySQL implementation working, right? So I would write a test suite for your MySQL implementation that has an actual running MySQL database in the background. Then you can make sure that the implementation actually works end-to-end. That's somewhat of a mix of an integration and unit test, I guess

Comment: This is great advice. Even a very simple interface that only implements the a "query()" function, where you pass a query string and it returns a promise, would allow for easy testing. The test could mock the resolved value or reject.throw result.

Comment: @fjc Can I have any MySql running on local host ? Something maybe managed by Workbenck and just pass the connection details in `mysql.createConnection()`?

Comment: @KarimFayed you could, that would not be very practical for a unit test though. Imagine anyone and anything wanting to run your tests now needs a running MySql instance.

Comment: @fjc Then what would you propose? I thought this is what you meant by the following:
" I would write a test suite for your MySQL implementation that has an actual running MySQL database in the background. Then you can make sure that the implementation actually works end-to-end. "

Comment: @KarimFayed for an e2e test, yes. For a unit test, no

Comment: @fjc I have followed your answer and created a wrapper class and database interface. Now I wish to implement jest and as "Pmits" I have a relatively skinny implementation so I'm confused which parts / functions should I test and which should I neglect or mock.
Can you please elaborate on this point?

Comment: Test your own logic, don't test another library's.

Answer (score 3):

There is a "brute-force" way if all you are really trying to do is to mock your MySQL calls.  The following code is in TypeScript, but should be easily adaptable to regular JavaScript.

```
import * as mysql from "mysql2/promise";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
jest.mock("mysql2/promise");

async function dbMethod(conn: mysql.Pool, field1Value: number): Promise<any> {
    return await (conn.execute("SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM foo WHERE field_1=?",
       [field1Value]) as Promise<mysql.RowDataPacket[]>);
}

describe("dbMethod", () => {
   let mockDB: mysql.Pool;
   beforeEach(() => {
      mockDB =  {
         execute: jest.fn()
      } as unknown as mysql.Pool;
   });
   it("should get something from database", async () => {
      const mockExecute = mocked(mockDB.execute);
      const testData = [{
         field_1: 123,
         field_2: 456
      }];

      mockExecute.mockResolvedValue([
         [testData] as mysql.RowDataPacket[],
         []
      ]);

      // Confirm results back from MySQL
      await expect(dbMethod(mockDB, 123)).resolves.toEqual([[testData], []]);

      // If you want, you can confirm MySQL execute was called as expected
      expect(mockExecute).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
         "SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM foo WHERE field_1=?",
         [123]
      );            
   });
});
```

Comment: i find this elegant and rather readable ;)